# Of all time or Of all times or Of all the time or Of all the times

Tags: determiners

1 Many people believe that she is among the top ten dancers of all **times**.

2 Many people believe that she is among the top ten dancers of all **time**.

3 I think it's the greatest song of all **times**.

4 I think it's the greatest song of all **time**.

Are these ever possible?

5 I think it's the greatest song of all the times.

6 I think it's the greatest song of all the time.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is **of all time**, meaning that something is the best example of its kind there has ever been.

**All time** refers (in a somewhat exaggerated way) to the whole of history, not to different 'times'. *All times* and *all the time(s)* are not possible in this context.